# Wait for a method completed first, before continue running

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm trying to run a method called **uploadProfilePhoto()** but the code after this method invocation runs first even though uploadProfilePhoto() has not finish running. Is there anyway i can let uploadProfilePhoto() finish it's process first before continuing?

I tried using AsynTask but it still doesn't work. Seems like it is because **doInBackground()** is for a series of code, not method.

**AsyncTask**

```
protected class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        uploadProfilePhoto();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Toast.makeText(ProfileSetup.this, "Account created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileSetup.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

**uploadProfilePhoto()**

```
private void uploadProfilePhoto() {

    if (mImageUri != null) {
        final StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        storageTask = imageReference.putFile(mImageUri);
        storageTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return imageReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                    String myid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");

                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(myid);
                    reference.child("profilePicUrl").setValue(myUrl);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileSetup.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSetup.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of your `uploadProfilePhoto` method executes after the onPostExecute?

Comment: your image in method uploadProfilePhoto()  is already getting uploaded asynchronously then why do you need to use an aynctask

Comment: you can say account created successfully in the compleListener

Comment: @RajanPrasad you mean which line of code the uploadProfilePhoto is running when onPostExecute finish executing?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan because i want the `uploadProfilePhoto()` to be uploaded first before it goes to **MainActivity**

Comment: @AhChing11 yes. Because as Abhinav pointed out, your uploadProfilePhoto already executes its stuff in non blocking code.

Comment: @AhChing11 can you please tell me the reason for that , can you explain what exactly you want to achieve i believe there is better way of doing it then what you're thinking

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan The problem here is that, in my **onCreate()** method in the **Login**Class, i called the `uploadProfilePhoto()` method. However,  while `uploadProfilePhoto()` is uploading to database, the code has already reached MainActivity where i will be checking whether the photo exists or not. So it caused **MainAcitivty** to not able to read the photo because photo upload is still in process and i want to avoid that. What should i do??

Comment: @RajanPrasad Above is my explanation

Comment: @AhChing11 your comment suggest that you want the main activity to open when the image is uploaded , so as you may know you will receive the onComplete callback from firebase in the onCompleteListener only when the the uploading is complete , so you can start you MainActivity in the onComplete() method, and if you receive the onFailure callback you can tell the user that image was not uploaded and he should try again

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways

```
 storageTask = imageReference.putFile(mImageUri);
    storageTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                myUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                String myid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
                DatabaseReference reference = 
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(myid);
                reference.child("profilePicUrl").setValue(myUrl);
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileSetup.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSetup.this, "Failed", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

2nd way which is not very clean and nice actually should be considered as a bad practice , but knowing alternative way is no harm so

you can start MainActivity Imidiately after saying `imageReference.putFlie(mImageUri);`

```
imgeReference.putFile(mImageUri);
startActivity(new Intent(ProfileSetup.this, MainActivity.class));
```

Now in the MainActivity

```
while(ProfileSetup.getImageUrl() == null){ // define a method to return the url
       Systemclock.sleep(500);            // if it is small image you can hote it will be uplaoded in seconds      
}
Picasso.with(this).load(ProfileSetup.getImageUrl()).fit().into(imageView); // the while loop terminates when your image gets uploaded because getImageUrl() did not return null , now you know image is there you can download and set it to imageView by using Piccaso
```

With this approach you don't need a completeListener but i don't recommend doing it because it is more complex and doesn't deal with any failure of imageUploading